# Passport js Sessions not working; req.user undefined on subsequent requests

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I've recently integrated Passport js into my app, but am struggling to set up login sessions. When logging in, serializeUser is called properly and req.user is present. On any subsequent request from the browser, however, req.user returns undefined and deserializeUser is not called.

When testing with postman, everything seems to work perfectly and requests can access req.user fine. This leads me to believe that passport is set up correctly in the back-end, and the issue lies with either CORS or some express setup. Below is what I have to handle CORS.

```
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');

  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
      next();
  }
});
```

I'm fairly new to CORS and working with login sessions, so I might be missing something incredibly simple. I've checked out similar posts on here, but haven't found a solution that works for me.

Since I'm using authenticate() as middleware, I don't think I need to call req.login (I've tried manually calling it just to check). I've also tried using the cors npm package and cookiesessions, but neither solve the issue.

I think it could be a problem with cookies, though I am not sure how to check this. For reference, I'm making axios requests with credentials being sent.

Here is my full repo if anyone wants to take a peek (on branch Login-Backend): https://github.com/SabrinaSnider/Chow

Thanks for any help!

Edit:

I'm using the express-session packed to handle sessions. Here is the code I use for session stuff. In './config/passport', I have my localstrateg and serialize/deserialize methods.

```
var session = require("express-session")

/* --- Passport setup --- */
app.use(session({
  secret: global.config.session.secret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// passport inits
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// passport strategy
require('./config/passport')
```

Comment: Can you share how are you sending your session details - HTTP header or a cookie?

Comment: I updated the post with information about how I use sessions. I'm not sure how to tell how sessions details are sent, but I assumed it was with cookies.

I make my front-end requests with axios and with credentials, which I think sends cookies.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?